# How to change letter spacing in a Textview?

Tags: android, textview, typeface

How can i change letter spacing in a textview?
Will it help if I have HTML text in it (I cannot use webview in my code).

P.S. I'm using my own typeface in the textview with HTML text.

Comment: In the layout editor you can do `android:letterSpacing=".05"` Where .05 would be roughly "50" in a program like **photoshop**

Answer (score 30, accepted):

check out [android:textScaleX](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:textScaleX)

Depending on how much spacing you need, this might help. That's the only thing remotely related to letter-spacing in the TextView.

**Edit:** *please see [@JerabekJakub's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28147048/2823516) below for an updated, better method to do this starting with api 21 (Lollipop)*

Comment: How would you translate that over to letter spacing?

Comment: Is there a way to increase/decrease the space between letters/characters? textScaleX - Literary scales the letters/characters.

Comment: @Barts answer does what the question is asking

Comment: @Kumaresan Yes, there is - since API 21, see my answer below.

Comment: @EricNovins did you ever find the answer to your question?

Comment: Scaling the text in the X axis is not the proper way to handle kerning or tracking in Android. There is an api for lollipop that accomplishes this however previous to lollipop you will need a custom text view to accomplish this.

Comment: I don't know how this solution got so many upvotes (+33, -24) are people just blindly putting up their votes? `letterSpacing` vs `textScaleX` what a huge difference

Comment: I tried putting normal spaces between each letter, it worked.

Comment: @JimitPatel - At the time the question was asked, letterSpacing option did not exist.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve that does not make me to write an answer to popular question with latest findings. That will help other users to get an answer easily. That was only my intention

Answer (score 266):

Since API 21 there is an option set letter spacing. You can call method [setLetterSpacing](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setLetterSpacing(float)) or set it in XML with attribute [letterSpacing](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:letterSpacing).

Comment: This doesnt actually work when set in the XML. I get an error like this: `"1.2dp" in attribute "letterSpacing" cannot be converted to float."`

Comment: @dopatraman You have to ommit units, type just value: android:letterSpacing="1.2" instead of android:letterSpacing="1.2dp"

Comment: Knowing that 31% of the devices don't support API 21, how would you do this in previous versions?

Comment: To be fair, according to Google there are more than 45% devices with API 21 and higher (June 2016). For lower API, you can check another answers here, for example Bart's below.

Comment: Note that the value of letterSpacing isn't in dp/sp, it is in 'EM' units. Typical values for slight expansion will be around 0.05. Negative values tighten text.

Comment: @JerabekJakub is there any alternative for using `letterSpacing` below API 21?

Comment: @JimitPatel Hi, as I said before, you can check other answers, for example Bart's answer below.

Comment: For some reason `letterSpacing` wasn't changing in the AS preview. I had to actually run the app on a physical device to see the change.

Comment: It's true - Android Studio design mode does NOT properly respect this parameter. Probably worthy of a bug write-up against the tool. *OR* don't report it and tell your manager you need a device just to test this. ;-)

Comment: if I toggle between numberPassword as the initial setting in xml and then swap to `inputField.setInputType(
                InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD);`, the masking bullets initially take up way less space until changed via Java. I was wondering how letterspacing can be used to keep spacing consistent when changing between these two types

Comment: @DrewSzurko the preview is almost never accurate in my experience!

Answer (score 116):

More space:

```
  android:letterSpacing="0.1"
```

Less space:

```
 android:letterSpacing="-0.07"
```

Comment: what is the default letterSpacing?

Comment: The default `letterSpacing` is 0.0 according to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#getLetterSpacing()

Comment: maybe add @Evin1_'s comment in ur answer

Comment: what is the maximum and minimum letterSpacing supported?

Answer (score 27):

This answer is based on Pedro's answer but adjusted so it also works if text attribute is already set:

```
package nl.raakict.android.spc.widget;
import android.content.Context;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.style.ScaleXSpan;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class LetterSpacingTextView extends TextView {
    private float letterSpacing = LetterSpacing.BIGGEST;
    private CharSequence originalText = "";


    public LetterSpacingTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public LetterSpacingTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
        originalText = super.getText();
        applyLetterSpacing();
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public LetterSpacingTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle){
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public float getLetterSpacing() {
        return letterSpacing;
    }

    public void setLetterSpacing(float letterSpacing) {
        this.letterSpacing = letterSpacing;
        applyLetterSpacing();
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
        originalText = text;
        applyLetterSpacing();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getText() {
        return originalText;
    }

    private void applyLetterSpacing() {
        if (this == null || this.originalText == null) return;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i < originalText.length(); i++) {
            String c = ""+ originalText.charAt(i);
            builder.append(c.toLowerCase());
            if(i+1 < originalText.length()) {
                builder.append("\u00A0");
            }
        }
        SpannableString finalText = new SpannableString(builder.toString());
        if(builder.toString().length() > 1) {
            for(int i = 1; i < builder.toString().length(); i+=2) {
                finalText.setSpan(new ScaleXSpan((letterSpacing+1)/10), i, i+1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
        }
        super.setText(finalText, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
    }

    public class LetterSpacing {
        public final static float NORMAL = 0;
        public final static float NORMALBIG = (float)0.025;
        public final static float BIG = (float)0.05;
        public final static float BIGGEST = (float)0.2;
    }
}
```

If you want to use it programatically:

```
LetterSpacingTextView textView = new LetterSpacingTextView(context);
textView.setSpacing(10); //Or any float. To reset to normal, use 0 or LetterSpacingTextView.Spacing.NORMAL
textView.setText("My text");
//Add the textView in a layout, for instance:
((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLinearLayout)).addView(textView);
```

Comment: is this added actually spaces between the characters? Boo... if someone copies this text it will include the extra spaces. No-Joy

Comment: Needs a `null` check in `applyLetterSpacing`, but other than that, life saver!

Comment: doesnt work when u set the text afterwords and then apply spacing programatically

Comment: @jonney it should,  I have it working like that. Could you send an example?

Comment: Ok when I get to the office I will.  Basically I added this view in xml and then  did a find view by id to get the object and changed the spacing and text programmatically and it did not change it.  If i dont set text the spacing works.  If i do settext the spacing only applies a small amount?  It's as if it can only apply  the big size amount but nothing greater than that at all

Comment: Hey, this doesn't work with ellipsis at the end of the text. Any ideas on how to fix that ?

Comment: What is the purpose of `c.toLowerCase()`?

Comment: @Ihunath to be completely honest, I don't remember. Try to remove it and see what happens

Comment: @BartBurg your code works great. but If TextView has spannable string already then this code removes it.

Comment: The no-break space - "\u00A0" - is really useful. Thanks

Answer (score 12):

after API >=21 there is inbuild method provided by TextView called `setLetterSpacing`

[check this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setLetterSpacing(float)) for more

Comment: How can to same in <21 ?

Comment: if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    this.setLetterSpacing(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.letter_spacing));
                }else{
                    this.setTextScaleX(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.letter_spacing));
                }

Answer (score 10):

I built a custom class that extends `TextView` and solves this problem... Check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16429758) =)

Answer (score 0):

As android doesn't support such a thing, you can do it manually with FontCreator. It has good options for font modifying.
I used this tool to build a custom font, even if it takes some times but you can always use it in your projects.

Answer (score -1):

For embedding HTML text in your textview you can use `Html.fromHTML()` syntax.
More information you will get from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: how does this help?  I'm not aware of an HTML tag for letter spacing that works in a TextView.