# How to make textviews really close on android?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I am currently building out a layout in Android but I am experiencing difficulty with lettering (the space between two textviews with one right above another) in Android. I am unable to decrease the size between the two textviews to my designers liking, even though I have no vertical margins set between the two textviews. The textview are ordered in a relative layout, with one textview right below the other. Here is the xml for the textviews:

```
<com.devspark.robototextview.widget.RobotoTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Auction Name"
    android:textColor="@color/LAgrey"
    android:id="@+id/tv_auctionTitle"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    app:typeface="roboto_regular"/>

<com.devspark.robototextview.widget.RobotoTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Auctioneer Name"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_auctionTitle"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/tv_auctioneerDetails"
    android:textSize="@dimen/auctionList_SubTitleTextSize"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textColor="#a7a6a6"
    app:typeface="roboto_black"/>
```

How can I make the vertical spacing even smaller between the two textfields? I can provide screenshots if necessary.

Comment: You can adjust them with negative margin/padding

Comment: Yes, I thought of that but I remember vaguely seeing somewhere that using negative values can cause issues sometimes. Have you ever heard or experienced any issues with negative margin/padding?

Comment: No, as long as you use dp and sp dimensions. But keep in mind that, if TextView seems to be padded, it's to avoid text collision

Comment: @AndrePerkins screen shots please.

Answer (score 0):

You may need a custom TextView - I've had this trouble before. There are two "padding" characteristics that are rarely adjusted and may require a custom `TextView` object.

1. Line spacing:

[android textview padding between lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863974/android-textview-padding-between-lines)

2. Font Padding:

[How to change letter spacing in a Textview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133548/how-to-change-letter-spacing-in-a-textview)