# Android - How can I reduce a TextView's letter spacing without using setLetterSpacing()?

Tags: android, textview, spacing, letter

I have tried making a custom TextView from Bart's answer here:

[How to change letter spacing in a Textview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133548/how-to-change-letter-spacing-in-a-textview)

But it doesn't seem to work for reducing the size of the spaces.  When I use 0 as an argument for setSpacing(), it increases the spaces size. I wonder if this is because I'm using a custom font?

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: To clarify, I'm working with API 14 and can't use `setLetterSpacing()`which is a thing since API 21.

Comment: DId it work? Accept my answer if it did. If you need more help, just ask

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are using the wrong method. Use this instead:

```
setLetterSpacing(0)
```

Not

```
setSpacing(0)
```

If that doesn't work, try to make an external font from any online software, and just add it to your text view. You will need to add it to a font directory and then access it from there:

```
TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Maximum.ttf");
textView. setTypeface(font);
```

You can find more information about using external fonts [here](http://javatechig.com/android/using-external-fonts-in-android-view).

Comment: I can't use setLetterSpacing() because I'm working with API 14 only.

Comment: Then try doing the external font thing I provided