# Is there any alternatives of letterSpacing attribute for EditText in API level 20 or below

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-api-levels

**I've added Why my question is not duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133548/how-to-change-letter-spacing-in-a-textview) question in Edit Section, Please review..**

---

We use [letterSpacing](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#letterSpacing) attribute in EditText to define the spacing between letters like [image: here in the picture].

But as per [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#letterSpacing), This was only introduced in API level 21 or above, If we try to use it in lower API level version, It shows rendering problem directly as in this picture[image: in this picture].

**Is there any alternatives for [letterSpacing](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#letterSpacing) to use in EditText before API level 20 ?**

---

---

**Edit**

It was marked as duplicate question but what I want to notify is `android:textScaleX` attribute and `android:letterSpacing` attribute is different.

Let's take an example by adding these two attributes in EditText

**The result of adding `android:letterSpacing` is**

[image: result of letterSpacing]

**And the result of adding `android:textScaleX` is**
[image: result2]

Comment: HI. check out this for (before API 21) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133548/how-to-change-letter-spacing-in-a-textview

Comment: @MitBhatt Once this question was marked as duplicate with the question you shared now. Again I edited the question and its re-opened now. please See whats different between them in edit section.

Comment: Check the Answer of Bart Burg in that link. that's why this Question is duplicate.

Comment: @MitBhatt Ok thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry you couldn't adjust **letterSpacing** in Api before 21 but you can adjust it if you draw text on `Canvas` using 2D graphics APIs.