# Letter-space in android-text view

Tags: java, android, kotlin, textview, letter-spacing

I would like to implement a letter spacing ( Increase/Decrease the spaces) and bind the same to slider control. I have already created a slider that scales the text, but unable to create the letter spacing option, since, I have no clue on how to do the same. The following is what I am trying to achieve
[image]

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/23216171/1343788

Comment: Thank you for the link. Let me have a look at the same.

Comment: On Lollipop or higher there's a built-in solution for this, as per this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28147048/4465208