# Letter Spacing on EditText is not working

Tags: android

I want to set letter spacing on a EditText but it is not working.

I tried to create the EditText like this:

```
 <EditText
                android:id="@+id/pin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/input_text_height"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_extra_large"
                local:MvxBind="Text PinCode"
                android:maxLength="6"
                android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:padding="6dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@drawable/editText_textColorState"
                android:background="@drawable/editText_borderOnFocus"
                android:letterSpacing="10"/>
```

The letter spacing attribute is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: android api version?

Comment: Android 5.0 - API 21

Comment: try to run the app on physical device

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133548/how-to-change-letter-spacing-in-a-textview

Comment: That`s what I am doing. I am not running the app on Emulator

Comment: Something to do with it having ** before and after it I reckon!

Comment: letter-spacing TeaxtView property, not Edittext. Please check on android documentation.

Comment: @Kam I have posted an answer. Please check

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`letterSpacing` need to be a float value. Try `android:letterSpacing="0.50"`

Like @mike points out Android Studio does render letter spacing in preview since V4.0

**Old Answer**

Android Studio doesn't render the letter spacing in the preview, so you will have to manual run it on a device to view the changes.

Comment: Just a little note for future readers: in Android Studio 4.0.1 and beyond letter spacing is updated in real time in the preview

Answer (score 2):

In the official documentation, they've mentioned that it requires a float value instead of an integer.

> **android:letterSpacing** Text letter-spacing.
>
> May be a floating point value, such as "1.2".

```
android:letterSpacing="1.2"
```

So, your EditText should look like this

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/pin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/input_text_height"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_extra_large"
    local:MvxBind="Text PinCode"
    android:maxLength="6"
    android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:padding="6dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@drawable/editText_textColorState"
    android:background="@drawable/editText_borderOnFocus"
    android:letterSpacing="10.0"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to ommit units, type just value:

`android:letterSpacing="1.2"`

For some reason letterSpacing wasn't changing in the AS preview. I had to actually run the app on a physical device to see the change