# How to increase the spacing between lines in a textview.?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to style the android fonts styles with leading and tracking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620325/is-it-possible-to-style-the-android-fonts-styles-with-leading-and-tracking)

How to increase the spacing between lines in a textview in android?

Comment: can you show which format you want?

Answer (score 183, accepted):

from code you can use `textView.setLineSpacing()` or from xml you can use `android:lineSpacingExtra`

Comment: what will be the value

Comment: @Prasad: Try reading Android documentation [android:lineSpacingExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:lineSpacingExtra)

Comment: android:lineSpacingExtra="-5dp". Negative values works.

Answer (score 99):

You can use lineSpacingExtra and lineSpacingMultiplier in your XML file.

```
android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
```

or a number greater than 1

```
android:lineSpacingExtra="xxdp"
```

Comment: A much better answer with more specifications

Comment: Be careful while using android:lineSpacingMultiplier. As value less than 1 will results into last line of Textview being cut of in sdk versions less than 21

Answer (score 14):

You can use this: `lineSpacingExtra="xxdp"`