# How make spacing between letters in Android TextView?

Tags: android, textview

I need make design from photoshop layout. There are some fonts on the layouts. 
Designer gave me this fonts. But on layout in photoshop, he use spacing between letters. How i can realize this in android textView? I found one solution:

[answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133548/how-to-change-letter-spacing-in-a-textview)

[answer two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14283246/change-text-kerning-or-spacing-in-textview)

but if i make `myTextView extends TextView` it work wrong. If i adapt for one devise, on the device with biger display,  spacing between letters increase is not proportional.

EDIT

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView {
    private float letterSpacing = 0.0f;
    private CharSequence originalText = "";
    private Typeface typeface;

    public MyTextView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
        isInEditMode();
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
        isInEditMode();
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        TypedArray attributesArray = getResources().obtainAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyTextView);
        letterSpacing = attributesArray.getDimension(R.styleable.MyTextView_letterSpacing, 0.0f);
        String fontName = attributesArray.getString(R.styleable.MyTextView_fontName);
        if(!this.isInEditMode()) {
            if (null == fontName) {
                typeface = Fonts.getBlockBertholdRegular(context);
            } else {
                typeface = Fonts.get(context, fontName);
            }
            super.setTypeface(typeface);
        }
        originalText = super.getText();
        applyLetterSpacing();
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public float getLetterSpacing() {
        return letterSpacing;
    }

    public void setLetterSpacing(float letterSpacing) {
        this.letterSpacing = letterSpacing;
        applyLetterSpacing();
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
        originalText = text;
        applyLetterSpacing();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getText() {
        return originalText;
    }

    private void applyLetterSpacing() {
        if (this == null || this.originalText == null) return;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < originalText.length(); i++) {
            String c = "" + originalText.charAt(i);
            builder.append(c.toUpperCase());
            if (i + 1 < originalText.length()) {
                builder.append("\u00A0");
            }
        }
        SpannableString finalText = new SpannableString(builder.toString());
        if (builder.toString().length() > 1) {
            for (int i = 1; i < builder.toString().length(); i += 2) {
                finalText.setSpan(new ScaleXSpan((letterSpacing + 1) / 10), i, i + 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
        }

        super.setText(finalText, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
        if(!this.isInEditMode()) {
            super.setTypeface(typeface);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "If i adapt for one devise" Could you show us the code in which you do that?

Comment: code no. I do it resize until they coincide with photoshop.

Comment: Did you try to create a custom `textView`? (`myTextView extends TextView`) If so, what's working wrong?

Comment: I'm writing this in the question. that it tried

Comment: Yes, but you didn't provide code or explanations of what went wrong! thanks for the code.

Comment: on the screen with a large dpi distance increases not proportionally.

Comment: try uaing android:lineSpacingExtra and android:letterSpacing

Comment: This is for lines; ip696 wants the spacing to be between letters

Comment: Docteur Yes, I want to just that. Exactly what I need to do it. I myself would not do it)

Comment: @ip696 See my answer below.

Comment: @ip696 you can also view this answer set http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1640659/how-to-adjust-text-kerning-in-android-textview/16429758#16429758

Comment: Make TextWatcher http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260083/letter-spacing-in-android-edittext/43995723#43995723

Answer (score 9):

Try using the new TextView API method `setLetterSpacing`.
[See here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setLetterSpacing(float))

**EDIT**

You can also [create your own font](http://birdfont.org/) with spaces inside the font itself and [apply it to your TextView](http://javatechig.com/android/using-external-fonts-in-android-view).

Comment: there isn't any setLetterSpanning method

Comment: You answered exactly the same thing than I did, and you say that my answer is incorrect?

Comment: As far as I know, this is only available in android 21

Comment: Yes; since you haven't mentioned an API I figured you were using the latest. Which one are you on?

Comment: check the word you'll find out the difference. I did post my answer on comment first you can see the time log

Comment: Wooops. Thanks, typo.

Comment: I admit that the minimum android 4.3

Comment: That's it Bro. You found out the difference

Comment: my English is bad. I wanted to say that I need it to work on android 4.3

Comment: A solution that would work in any API would be drawing the text in a `Canvas` / `2DGraphic` with a custom font.

Comment: Yes I have seen this answer. but never tried it. because I do not understand how to do it

Comment: You would need to create a custom font before - do you know how to do that?

Comment: I tried to do it. but from another program. and could not. Now try again

Answer (score 5):

Since API 21 You can use

```
setLetterSpacing
```

Documentation can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setLetterSpacing%28float%29)

Comment: As far as I know, this is only available in android 21

Comment: @ip696 yes this is available from API 21 only

Comment: It should work. I am using same coding on my program right now on API 21

Comment: distance increases is not proportional

Comment: @ip696 AFAIK it is device dependant I think but I am not sure.

Comment: Just because it took me a bit to figure out, 0 represents no letter spacing, so a slight spacing would be 0.2 (not 1.2)