# Letter spacing in Android EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I am trying to Display a text box with letters separated by spaces.

```
    EditText wordText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.word_text);
    wordText.setPaintFlags(wordText.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
    InputFilter[] filterArray = new InputFilter[2];
    filterArray[0] = new InputFilter.AllCaps();
    filterArray[1] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(10);
    wordText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

Here's the layout file.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/match_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp">

    <EditText android:id="@+id/word_text"
        android:layout_width="200dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Your Word"
        android:maxLength="15"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/match_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="start"
        android:text="Match"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

How can I add space between letters in API 12. I dont want to use setLetterSpacing().

Also, when I start typing, setGravity(Gravity.CENTER) is causing my letters to appear from the center of the box. How do i make it appear from Left to right ? If I set Gravity.LEFT, the EditText itself moves to the left in the LinearLayout. Can anyone help ?

Comment: Why you don't want to use setLetterSpacing()? And for alignment of text use android:layout_gravity="left" in your XML layout or appropriate API function. It can also ask you for usage of android:layout_gravity="start".

Comment: I suggest you add the layout file also,

Comment: As i mentioned, i get compiler error since my minSdk is API 12 where setLetterSpacing isnt available. And when I use Gravity.Left, my EditText itself moves to the left of the screen. I want it to be positioned in the center, but when I type, letters should appear from left. Is it possible to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

The subject of letter spacing seems to have caused quite some traffic over the years. Some preach for using `textScaleX` property, but that by itself is not an acceptable solution, because it skews the letters as well. Several other solutions that were mentioned are:

1. Create a custom font and add you own spacing there. It is convoluted though, because it involves copyright and not-so-dynamic spacing between letters
2. Adding spaces in between letters - also not so desirable, because there is not enough granularity when it comes to increases in spacing values
3. A combination of `textScaleX` and adding spaces between letters - it involves a custom view where `textScaleX` is applied only to the spaces - so the letters remain unchanged, only the space increases-decreases. You can use the non breakable space unicode character as well. For this solution you can check out
   [Change text kerning or spacing in TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14283246/change-text-kerning-or-spacing-in-textview)

Answer (score 1):

1. Make TextWatcher (this example for enter only digits into EditText field, you can change it if necessary)

   ```
   public class CustomTextWatcher implements TextWatcher{

       private static final char space = ' ';

   public CodeTextWatcher (){}

   @Override
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

   }

   @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
   }

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

       // Remove all spacing char
       int pos = 0;
       while (true) {
           if (pos >= s.length()) break;
           if (space == s.charAt(pos) && (((pos + 1) % 2) != 0 || pos + 1 == s.length())) {
               s.delete(pos, pos + 1);
           } else {
               pos++;
           }
       }

       // Insert char where needed.
       pos = 1;
       while (true) {
           if (pos >= s.length()) break;
           final char c = s.charAt(pos);
           // Only if its a digit where there should be a space we insert a space
           if ("0123456789".indexOf(c) >= 0) {
               s.insert(pos, "" + space);
           }
           pos += 2;
       }
   }
   ```

   }
2. Attach this textWatcher to your EditText:

   ```
    EditText.addTextChangedListener(new CustomTextWatcher());
   ```