# How to Distributed Text in Android like Microsoft Word?

Tags: java, android, textview

The first line is normal ways to show text on textview.
How I can show like the second ways?
[image]

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: what's is your initial element  ? 
A number or a string ? 

you could  always add some tab between each caracter to obtain the 2nd way.

Comment: That is String, one line just only 16 characters. I have two line. How I can do it ?

Comment: If you want to have direct control over letter spacing, this is possible in Lollipop and above by changing the `letterSpacing` attribute in your `TextView`. Else, consider [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1640659/how-to-adjust-text-kerning-in-android-textview/16429758#16429758) answer by Pedro.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for text that expands the spaces in between to take up whatever area, that's called "justified text". As far as I know it's not currently supported natively in android. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292575/android-textview-justify-text) has quite a number of workarounds, though, from custom textviews to using webviews.

**EDIT**

The below method does not appear to work anymore, or at least it didn't when I plugged it in to try it out. I would suggest using a custom view in that case. Refer to the link for more information.

<del>Probably the easiest way would be using a webview (poached from the link):</del>

```
<!--create a webview in xml-->
<WebView
 android:id="@+id/textContent"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

<del>and then in your activity you do:</del>

```
WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.textContent);
String text; 
text = "<html><body><p align=\"justify\">"; 
text+= "123456789";
text+= "</p></body></html>";
view.loadData(text, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Comment: Sorry but nothing change, result same the fist line.

Comment: Could you post some of your current implementation?

Comment: Hmm--okay, I tried it out and apparently it doesn't work anymore. That's strange. You may have to use one of the custom views in the link above, then.

Answer (score -1):

```
String temp = "";
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    temp=temp+i+" ";
}
textView1.setText(temp);
```